# Value of $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod\limits_{k=3}^n\left(1-\tan^4\frac{\pi}{2^k}\right)=\frac{\pi^3}{m}$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Find the value of m for the following $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=3}^n\left(1-\tan^4\frac{\pi}{2^k}\right)=\frac{\pi^3}{m}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried up to $(1-tan^4\theta)=sec^4\theta(cos2\theta)$ but not able to make any telescopic function

Comment: All caps is the internet equivalent of yelling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to find a closed form for your product, if fact we have for any $ k\geq 3 $ :

\begin{aligned}1-\tan^{4}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}&=\frac{1-\tan^{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}}{\cos^{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}}\\ &=\frac{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}\right)}}{\cos^{4}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}}\\ 1-\tan^{4}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}&=\frac{8\sin^{3}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}}{\sin^{3}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}\right)}}\times\frac{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}\right)}}{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}}\end{aligned}

Thus, if $ n\geq 3 $, then : \begin{aligned}\prod_{k=3}^{n}{\left(1-\tan^{4}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}\right)}&=8^{n-2}\left(\prod_{k=3}^{n}{\frac{\sin^{3}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}}{\sin^{3}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}\right)}}}\right)^{3}\left(\prod_{k=3}^{n}{\frac{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}\right)}}{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k}}\right)}}}\right)\\ &=2^{3n-5}\frac{\sin^{3}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}}{\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n}}\right)}}\end{aligned}

Comment: I think that final should be $2^{3n-5}$, not $8^{3n-5}$. Also, taking to the limit it becomes $\pi^3/32$.

Comment: @marty cohen True.

Answer (score 3):

Long, but detailed
$$\prod_{k=3}^n\left(1-\tan^4\frac{\pi}{2^k}\right)=
\prod_{k=3}^n\left(1-\tan^2\frac{\pi}{2^k}\right)\left(1+\tan^2\frac{\pi}{2^k}\right)=\\
\prod_{k=3}^n\left(\frac{\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}-\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}{\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}\right)\left(\frac{\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}+\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}{\cos^2{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}\right)\overset{\cos{2x}=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}}{=}\\
\prod_{k=3}^n\frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}}}{\cos^4{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}=
\frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}\cdot\prod_{k=3}^n\frac{1}{\cos^3{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}=\\
\frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}\cdot\prod_{k=3}^n\frac{\color{red}{\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}}{\color{red}{\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}\cdot\cos^3{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}\overset{\sin{2x}=2\sin{x}\cos{x}}{=}\\
\frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}\cdot\prod_{k=3}^n\frac{\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}{\frac{1}{2^3}\cdot\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}}}=
2^{3(n-2)}\cdot\frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}\cdot\prod_{k=3}^n\frac{\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2^k}}}{\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2^{k-1}}}}=\\
2^{3(n-2)}\cdot\frac{\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}\cdot\frac{\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}{\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{4}}}=
2^{3n-5}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}\cdot\sin^3{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}=\\
\frac{\pi^3}{2^5}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\right)^3\to\frac{\pi^3}{2^5}, n\to\infty$$
given that
$$\cos{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\to \cos{0}=1, n\to\infty$$
[and](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)
$$\frac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}}{\frac{\pi}{2^n}}\to 1, n\to\infty$$

Comment: That what Wolfy says with product up to 100. Upvoted.